# In an ODBC linked Access table, what determines the Field Size, and how can I change it?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that is linked to MS SQL Server through an ODBC connection. From what I can tell, Access somehow determines the Field Size and data type. In one of my fields, Access decided to set the field size to 7, when it should be 8. For a number of records, the last digit is being truncated! Access also has set the Datatype to Short Text. When ever I try to change either of these fields, I get the error "Operation is not supported for this type." Does anyone know how access determines the field size/data type, and how to change it for an ODBC linked table?

Edit: In my SQL table, the data displays properly. The truncation only occurs after the ODBC link in Access. Data type is nvarchar(50)

Comment: Access gets DDL from SqlServer at time the ODBC connection is established.  Any further changes at SqlServer are not known until the ODBC connection is dropped and re-established.

Comment: What is the exact data type in SQL Server?

Comment: *Data type is nvarchar(50)* -- and Access links that column as `Text(49)` ??

Answer (score 0):

is the field in question  datetime2?
The standard "legacy" driver installed  on windows by default (since xp days I think) does not see the later "newer" types of columns used in SQL server.

So, if you use SQL server driver, then Access will actually see that column as a string (text) and not a datetime column.
The fix is:
Use a native 11 or newer sql ODBC driver. This works, but then you have to ensure and install the native 11 (or later) driver on each workstation.

The other possible is to change the datetime2 to a datetime column server side, and re-link using the long time (and older) legacy SQL server driver.

However, even with the standard SQL driver installed by default on on recent editions of windows, I not seen the truncation you describe. I would suggest you try using a newer native 11 (or 13 or even later version). This may well fix your issue, but then you have to ensure that this newer driver of the same version is installed on each workstation.

I still use the legacy SQL server driver and thus this avoids me having to install a newer ODBC driver on each workstation, but in turn for this favor, I have to avoid the newer SQL server data column types available such as datetime2 columns.

I would try re-linking with a newer native 11 or later driver - see if that fixes this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the data type is nvarchar 50 characters

Comment: I not seen this type of issue. So deleting the link, and re-creating the link still shows this? And deleting and trying say native 11 vs that of the legacy sql driver also shows this? And for all testing, you always delete the table link and re-create it?